# How do I look up my current version of Chrome on CLI (Mac OSX)?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line-interface

Is there a way to access my current version of Chrome browser from the command line on Mac OSX?

For example, I'd like to type something like `google-chrome --version` to receive my version number as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version` should work

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!